# Putting an image as a link

Tags: support

I noticed that the imgur images come in with a stack exchange URL versus when I do one manually, it doesn't.

I wanted to put a link to an image in a post, so I'm attaching this here.

If this post gets deleted, will that imgur file be deleted?  What if more than one post uses the imgur file?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imgur generally does not delete images. Like, at all. There are ways to get image down, of course, but nothing automatic.

By the way, you can add image to a post, and then remove `!`, changing from

```
![Valid XHTML](http://w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10)
```

to

```
[Valid XHTML](http://w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10)
```

to make it display as just a link.